# Drop columnns from dataframe where last three characters equal

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I wish to only select particular columns from a dataframe, however the columns I don't want all end with `"Nav"`.

How can I accomplish this?

I've tried something similar to the below

```
jsonDF2.select([c for c in jsonDF2.columns if c not in {'%Nav'}])
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Currently using

```
#jsonDF2 = jsonDF2.select("d.*")
```

because I'm exploding some JSON that is nested in "d." so using blackbishops code, it currently places all the JSON within one column, instead of multiples screenshots of example below:

Code Used & Result:

```
jsonDF2 = jsonDF2.select("d.*")
```

[image]

**Suggested Code**

```
jsonDF2.select(*[F.col(c) for c in jsonDF2.columns if not c.endswith("Nav")])
```

[image]

I've tried place the d. prior the the * in the suggested code but got no joy. I know that "F" is obviously for the import. I tried also place the d. before the "c" and got no joy as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

jsonDF2.select(*[F.col(c) for c in jsonDF2.columns if not c.endswith("Nav")])
```

Comment: Hi, I've updated my question above as I am missing a bit I've not been clear on. I'm exploding JSON so the column is prefixed with a the letter d and using this code doesn't show the dataframe as expected. PLease see above.

Comment: @Lynchie first do `df = jsonDF2.select("d.*")` then `df.select(*[F.col(c) for c in df.columns if not c.endswith("Nav")])`

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
[c for c in jsonDF2.columns if c[-3:] != 'Nav']
```

Answer (score 0):

##### [`DataFrame.colRegex`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.colRegex.html)

You can use `colRegex` which is available in `spark >= 2.3`

```
df.select(df.colRegex('`.*(?<!nav)`'))
```